# Catch errors from ffmpeg in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling, pipe

I am trying to make a bashscript to allow mass converting a couple of moviefiles with the help of ffmpeg.

`ffmpeg` works great alone by itself, but when I run it as shown below - nothing seems to become appended to my logfile. What am I doing wrong?

```
ffmpeg -i "$input" -c:v mpeg4 -vtag divx -sameq -aspect 16:9 -r 25 "$output" >> ~/Desktop/logfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
ffmpeg -i "$input" -c:v mpeg4 -vtag divx -sameq -aspect 16:9 -r 25 "$output" > ~/Desktop/logfile.txt  2>&1
```

It redirect both `STDOUT` and `STDERR`. Some bits shorter version is:

```
ffmpeg -i "$input" -c:v mpeg4 -vtag divx -sameq -aspect 16:9 -r 25 "$output" &>> ~/Desktop/logfile.txt
```